# from activity back to fragment,some layout can't visiable and gone

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

in my fragment, I have a layout.when click the button,show it.and when i click it again I set the visibility to Gone.
but I set the layout visible and gone don't work when I jump to an activity and back to the fragment.then I getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE and ==View.GONE, the layout really is visible and gone. but the fragment can't show it.

```
private void beginTransaction(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
}
```

I doubt my fragment have some problem because when I try to use Fragment.replace to replace difference fragment, the fragment can't load some data. but I copy the replace code form my last project and the old project don't have any problem.
I use these code to solve the old problem.

```
    bottomBar.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startHomeFragment();
        }
    });
```

but I don't know how to solve the new problem now

Comment: explanation to your problem is not clear.

Comment: add your button onclicklistener code and please clearify your question